# Rendering the content of a page inside a div using ng-include based on the href of an element?

Tags: angularjs

If I have two list items

```
<li><a href="foo.html"></a></li>
<li><a href="bar.html"></a></li>
```

and based on which is clicked, to use ng-include to render in a div on the current page?

```
<div ng-controller="main-panel" class="main-panel">
    <ng-include src="'clickedElement'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

I am confused as to how to use routes to render an html inside a div, which is decided by which element you click?

```
main.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'side-menu'
   })

  .when('/signup', {
    templateUrl : 'signup.html',
    controller: 'main-panel'
   });

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat="oucampus in secondaryLinks.oucampus">
  <a ng-href='{{oucampus.href}}'> {{oucampus.title}} </a>
</li>
<div class="main-panel" ng-view></div>
```

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
oucampus: [
        {title: "Requests", href:"signup.html"},
    ],
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZhibUoR6F8B0p4KEm5eZ?p=preview)

Comment: In your `ng-repeat` try changing the `href` value to either `"#/signup"` or `"/signup"`

Comment: I further updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr4YNG5BKShQmCAkkFtu?p=preview) to show the sample `signup.html` with a controller with identifier `main-panel`.

Comment: A few things with plunker that can be causing issues. 1) You are not registering `ngRoute` in your angular application `main`, which is necessary for routing to work. 2) You do not have any routes specified in your `main.config()` 3) ngRoute was not being loaded. Here is a forked plunker, the `"/pending"` route is working for sake of example. Hopefully that helps! Also keep in mind that HTML5 mode usually requires additional configuration, especially in tools like Plunker.

Comment: My apologies I forgot to freeze my changes. Everything you stated had already been added.

Comment: Here is an example using HTML5 mode [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeyJ3tqqJXLhRELHI1Se?p=preview). The /pending route is the only one configured to work but you can use that to build out the rest of the route.

Comment: Bingo! And it's working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to render HTML content based on routes, you would want to use a routing service such as [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) or [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/). `ng-include` isn't the best option for implementing routing within your angular application.

With `ngRoute`, you use a directive `ng-view` to have angular load html/controllers/etc based on route specified/configured in your applications `config()` method into some DOM element. This is triggered when you click on an `<a>` that has an `ng-href` with a corresponding path or programatically in something like a controller using the `$location` service `path()` method.

**Route Configuration:**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/foo', {
      templateUrl: 'foo.html',
      controller: 'FooController'
    })
    .when('/bar', {
      templateUrl: 'bar.html',
      controller: 'BarController'
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a ng-href="#/foo">foo</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#/bar">bar</a></li>
</ul>

<div ng-view></div>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr4YNG5BKShQmCAkkFtu?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality of basic routing including loading specific controllers and HTML templates based on a specific route.

**ng-include**
If you absolutely need to use `ng-include`, you can using a function executed via `ng-click` attached to $scope or controllerAs to update the `src` property of `ng-include` to load a template based on a click element. I've updated the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cr4YNG5BKShQmCAkkFtu?p=preview).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yours works great, however on my end, I am still unable to display any html templates. See revised post.

Comment: Try it without HTML5 mode activated and try changed the href property from `"signup.html"` to `"#/signup"`. You want target the route rather than the file name of the HTML file.

Comment: Changed the <li> hrefs to '#/' and dropped the .html and still nothing. I am able to redirect to that link, but it does not render itself into that div.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Are you able to make it work with HTML5 mode? HTML5 mode requires additional configuration.

Comment: No errors are displaying in console. I'm going to update my original question with plunker attached