# Angular: How to implement ng-include like functionality in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-ng-include, angular5

Is there any functionality to render html file dynamically inside a components template based on the path? I have the path to local html file now I need to display the content of it inside a components template. In Anular 1.x we had ng-include, any similar functionality in Angular5?

```
<div class="row blogdetail-container">
        {{blogSelected.description}} // currently interpolates the path
</div>
```

variable `blogSelected.description` contains the path to html file and I want to replace its content here.

Comment: its not possible  but you can use custom pipe here

Comment: try watching this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036767/rendering-the-content-of-a-page-inside-a-div-using-ng-include-based-on-the-href

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the only reasonably straight-forward way I can think of to do this is to use an http request to get the contents of the html file then use that in the `[innerHtml]` attribute.

`private dynamicTemplate: any = "";
http.get(blogSelected.description).map((html:any) => this.dynamicTemplate = sanitizer.sanitize(html));`

then use

```
<div class="row blogdetail-container" [innerHtml]="dynamicTemplate"></div>
```

***NOTE 1:*** remember to include http as a dependency for this component.

***NOTE 2:*** remember to include sanitizer as a dependency for this component

***NOTE 3:*** remember to validate `blogSelected.description` before calling the http request to check it's actually a valid URL.

Comment: blogSelected.description is a component level property and can not be accessed in imports.

Comment: If this is Angular, you probably want to sanitize that html before you pass it to the DOM, also. `sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.html, dynamicTemplate)`

Comment: @vincecampanale Good shout; i'll update the answer :)

Comment: @VishalGulati Have you had a chance to try this out?

Comment: @George yes it kind of works but it requires one more http request. Wa thinking if we could implement this without forcing one more req to get the html content which basically ng-include does for us.

Comment: @VishalGulati there's unfortunately no like-for-like feature in Angular 5. There's quite a lengthy discussion [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7596).

TLDR: it prevents offline compilation and is a security risk

Comment: this example yielded nothing for me... console.log of 'this.dynamicTemplate' was empty
I hardcoded google.com as a test. this.http.get('http://google.com/').map((html:any) => this.dynamicTemplate = sanitizer.sanitize(html,this.dynamicTemplate)); - NO errors, but NO value either